# Android 10 Passkey authentication issue

Tags: android, ios, flutter, passkey

Today, I'm reaching out for help from everyone, especially those who have experience with Passkeys.

The situation is that I'm implementing Passkeys for a Flutter app, but I'm encountering some issues on Android 10. Specifically, the Register flow works fine, but when I try to Login, I get the following error:

`Google Sign-In (beginSignIn) fails with Missing Feature{name=auth_api_credentials_begin_sign_in, version=8}`

I followed the document here: https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/passkeys - I've tried it on Android 13 and both register/login work fine.*

I've tried different dependencies and updated CreationOptions, but it doesn't seem to improve.
Thank you everyone for taking the time to read this post.

I've tried different dependencies and updated CreationOptions

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of plain text. Just copy and paste the text into your question and format it as code.